# How to use struct and malloc in C99

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I need to translate my C++ code into C99:

```
struct TransferData  {
    int data[256];
} *readData;    

readData = (TransferData  *) malloc(sizeof(struct TransferData));
```

I nearly tried everything but get compiler errors each time.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You should post some of the compiler errors also.

Comment: [Note that casting the result of `malloc` is considered bad style in `C`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1171191) (while it is necessary in `C++`, although you probably shouldn't be using `malloc` in the first place).

Answer (score 4):

For `C` you need to cast to `struct TransferData *`, not to `TransferData *`. You don't have a type named `TransferData *` (or drop the cast altogether, but it's another holy war, pointless IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

You can either do as @icepack said, or change your struct definition like so:

```
typedef struct  {
    int data[256];
} TransferData;

TransferData *readData;
readData = malloc(sizeof(TransferData));
```

**Edit:** Note that it's preferable to use `sizeof` with variables instead of types to avoid repetition:

```
readData = malloc(sizeof(*readData));
```

But be careful not to accidentally pass the size of a pointer when using this style.

Without the `typedef`, you need to write `struct StructType` in C, which you don't need in C++. As said in the comments, casting the result of `malloc` is unnecessary in C, and just clutters your code. It is necessary in C++, but you shouldn't be using `malloc` there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `C`, you should not cast the result of `malloc`. It's a bad style to repeat type information. Also, the type of the structure is `struct TransferData` and not `TransferData` as in `C++`. I suggest

```
readData = malloc(sizeof(*readData));
```